# Use of log of an independent variable and its implications

Tags: regression, logarithm

I am currently analyzing the relationship between Google Search frequency and the CDS market. I used a monthly backward rolling regression to determine the 30 search queries which have the biggest  impact on the CDX index measured in the t-statistic for each month. In the next step I want to construct a sentiment index consisting of the Google Search Volume Index (SVI) for the 30 queries for the respective period. Eg when I want to construct the Sentiment Index for February 2011 I take the SVIs of the 30 queries with the highest t-statistic in the regression on the CDX Index for the timeframe January 2004-January 2011. When I want to construct the index for March 2011 I take the respective top 30 queries for January 2004 - February 2011 etc.

As the SVIs are scaled from 0-100 (Index is scaled relatively to the highest score in the observed period), naturally there a "bumbs" in my index when the components of the index (the query SVIs) change in case I use the levels of the SVIs in my sentiment. These bumbs will render my sentiment index ineffective.

Alternatively I expected to use the log (ln) of the change between two observations of the queries to be a way to circumvent the bumps, but unfortunately the results for the regression of the CDX on the Log change of SVI is not significant. Other studies on the other hand do show that the log change is indeed significant when using stock market returns (which naturally have a high correlation with the CDX levels), which makes the observed lack in explanatory power in my analysis look even stranger.

My question is, is it possible that although the level of the SVIs is highly significant at 0.1% (t>40), the log change is not? And if so, what is the reason? Do I miss a mechanism that increases the explanatory power of log variables?

Thanks